# How to change some properties by using JSONata without describing all of not changed properties?

Tags: jsonata

I have a JSON which is quite big, and I want to keep it and just make some changes. How to do it by using JSONata without describing each property.

I would expect to have operator which take all already existing properties and I just need to add overrides.

For example

```
{
   $takeall,
   "name": title //changes
   "area": width * height
}
```

Any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is the *[Transform Operator](https://docs.jsonata.org/other-operators#-------transform)*.

From the JSONata documentation:

> **... ~> | ... | ... | (Transform)**
> The object transform operator is used
> to modify a copy of an object structure using a pattern/action syntax
> to target specific modifications while keeping the rest of the
> structure unchanged.
> The syntax has the following structure:
>
> head ~> | location | update [, delete] |

Assuming your object looks something like this:

```
{
  "width": 5,
  "height": 5,
  "someOtherProps": "something",
  "title": "MyOlditle"
}
```

You can run this example query using the Transform Operator:

```
$ ~> | $ | {
    "area": width * height,
    "title": "myNewTitle"
}, ["height", "width"] |
```

To produce:

```
/** "someOtherProps" carried over from original object. **/
/** "height" and "width" removed after calculation. **/
{
  "someOtherProps": "something",
  "title": "myNewTitle",
  "area": 25
}
```

Working example: https://try.jsonata.org/dLm34sftc